# Special character from mysql to a php form

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have a problem with a simple character. I am trying to print `º` from mysql but I always get �.
Database is set to utf8, connection and meta too.

```
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: Look at the raw bytes and check if you're getting what you're expecting.

Comment: did u check the file encoding in your editor?